# How to load instances in a hierarchy with circular references just once?

Tags: c#, .net, hierarchy, circular-reference

I have a object structure like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    IList<Relationship> Relationships{get;set;}
}

public class Relationship
{
    public Relationship(Entity parent, IList<Entity> children)
    {
    //set properties
    }
    Entity Parent{get;private set;}
    IList<Entity> Children{get;private set;}
}
```

The Relationship contains all information about the parent and child instances, and I would like to share the same Relationship instance on the parent and all child instances that make up the relationship.

Now when I come to load my entities from the db I start with the top entity, which then loads the relationships. I thought I could just cache the relationship I am building and reuse the same instance for the children.  But this doesn't work as to create a relationship I need to load all child entities, so each child entity tries to recreate the same relationship I am currently trying to get the children for before it has been created, so I end up creating all of the relationship instances below me in the tree before I can add the relationship to the cache.

Is there a way I can get round this without making the children a settable property of my relationship, so I can create the reference to the relationship before the children are created?

Comment: Why do you need Relationships to be a list in the parent class and Children to be a list in the relationship class?  Shouldn't one list be good enough to establish a relationship to many children?  Couldn't you make Relationship or Chilredn be a single reference and only leave one of these as a list?  This doesn't answer your question, but would help me understand it.

Comment: in reality an entity has a type and each relationship is a relationship between the entity and other entities of particular type.  I simplified things for the purposes of the question

Comment: Could you use "ghost" Relationships while you create the entities? Then you "fix" the Relationships with the real thing. Not sure if this makes any sense. Also, this might also work against your cache.

Comment: It looks like you can load a child entity without loading all of its relationships.  Can you show at least an outline of the code that loads the relationships for an entity?  I wonder why you couldn't just complete loading the parent relationships and add them all to a cache before beginning on the child relationships, at which point you'll be able to look at the cache.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN you can't load the parent relationships and add them to the cache before loading the child relationships as there are no parent or child relationships, there is just a relationship, which contains both parents and children.  to create a relationship you need to have the parent instance and child instances already loaded

Comment: But it looks like you are allowed to have 0 children.  Why not leave the children at 0 until you know what they are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed this by introducing a RelationshipBuilder class which I used to keep track of the parents and children of a relationship without actually creating it.

This enabled me to load an entity and create its relationships in the builder, when the relationships tried to create the children they checked with the builder to see that the relationship was already being created and returned.

This meant I could navigate all the way down the hierarchy loading all of the entity instance and setting the parent entity and child entities associated with the relationships.  Once all of the entities had been loaded and the recursion had completed and we were returned to the entry point where we started loading the entities I ask the relationship builder to resolve all the relationships.  This then creates each relationship it has been informed about and sets the relationship instance on the parent and child instances which are involved in that relationship.